# Sending data to Xively using Arduino mega + Gprs shield sim 900

Tags: arduino, gprs, xively

I am using Arduino Mega2560 and GPRS Shield Sim900 and trying to send data to Xively using the code below.

What should I change in this code to send data to Xively with Sim900 GPRS Shield?

```
/*
 * Xively WiFi Sensor Tutorial
 *
 * This sketch is designed to take sensors (from photocell) and
 * upload the values to Xively at consistant intervals. At the
 * same time it gets a setable value from Xively to adjust the
 * brigthness of an LED. This sketch is reusable and can be
 * adapted for use with many different sensors.
 *
 * Derived from Xively Ardino Sensor Client by Sam Mulube.
 *
 * By Calum Barnes 3-4-2013
 * BSD 3-Clause License - [http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause]
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Calum Barnes
*/

#include <SPI.h> 
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>
#include <Xively.h>

char ssid[] = "SSID_HERE"; //  your network SSID (name) 
char pass[] = "PASS_HERE"; // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for     WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;          // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

// Your Xively key to let you upload data
char xivelyKey[] = "API_KEY_HERE";
//your xively feed ID
#define xivelyFeed FEED_ID_HERE
//datastreams
char sensorID[] = "LIGHT_SENSOR_CHANNEL";
char ledID[] = "LED_CHANNEL";

// Analog pin which we're monitoring (0 and 1 are used by the Ethernet shield)
#define sensorPin A2
//led connected pin
#define ledPin 9

// Define the strings for our datastream IDs
XivelyDatastream datastreams[] = {
  XivelyDatastream(sensorID, strlen(sensorID), DATASTREAM_FLOAT),
  XivelyDatastream(ledID, strlen(ledID), DATASTREAM_FLOAT),
};
// Finally, wrap the datastreams into a feed
XivelyFeed feed(xivelyFeed, datastreams, 2 /* number of datastreams */);

WiFiClient client;
XivelyClient xivelyclient(client);

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm \n");
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //pin setup
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("Starting single datastream upload to Xively...");
  Serial.println();

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, keyIndex, pass);
    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  } 
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
}

void loop() {
  //adjust LED level. set from Xively
  int getReturn = xivelyclient.get(feed, xivelyKey);    //get data from xively
  if (getReturn > 0) {
    Serial.println("LED Datastream");
    Serial.println(feed[1]);
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP Error");
  }

  //write value to LED - change brightness
  int level = feed[1].getFloat();
  if (level < 0) {
    level = 0;
  } else if (level > 255) {
    level = 255;
  }

  //actually write the value
  digitalWrite(ledPin, level);

  //read sensor values
  int sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  datastreams[0].setFloat(sensorValue);

  //print the sensor valye
  Serial.print("Read sensor value ");
  Serial.println(datastreams[0].getFloat());

  //send value to xively
  Serial.println("Uploading it to Xively");
  int ret = xivelyclient.put(feed, xivelyKey);
  //return message
  Serial.print("xivelyclient.put returned ");
  Serial.println(ret);
  Serial.println("");


  //delay between calls
  delay(15000);
}
```

Comment: should i use other libraries???

Comment: It's quite hard to get this SIM900 shield to work, I haven't heard of anyone having any luck with it. Official Arduino/Telefonica shield should be much easier though.

Comment: SIM900 works like a charm for me this error isn't because SIM900 module is somewhere faulty, I have myself used it in automotive 2G net connections and for consumer electronic purposes, CHeck your AT commands with what is there in the SIM900 Datasheet